# Do players get better by being played with the same profile?

Tags: fifa-12

Me and my friend play FIFA 12 at an arcade. He thinks by playing the game with the same profile over and over (in kick-off mode) will increase the performance of the players. I however think this is not true. Since we are playing at an arcade I believe that some player might have increased the performance of the players.

I checked the user gameplay settings in game setting and found something like this (Image is taken from my PC). Could this be the reason?

[image]

I would like to know what the case is: Do players get better performance when playing with the same profile more often or not?

Answer (score 1):

As I know the players only become better if you play Career Mode  (Single Player only). And even then, the Player stats in Arcade Mode should ever stay unchanged.

Comment: Hey I've edited my post. Is user gameplay customisation should remain 50 as default or it has been altered manually?